# Azure Logic App Customer Connector not working with oAuth2 (shock!) - this time with Pinterest

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, power-apps-custom-connector

I have access to the Pinterest v5 api and have successfully authorised my Pinterest App on a couple of Pinterest accounts via Postman using Oauth2 and can run queries against those accounts. I've then created an Azure Logic App Custom Connector with Oauth2 authentication using the exact details as used in Postman (different Redirect URI of course). I can successfully add an action (List Boards) from the custom connector to a logic app. After adding the action I click the 'sign in' button on the action, the pop-up appears and I can see it hitting the right Pinterest account, but the 'authorise' window never appears, it just hangs. Postman works every time with Oauth2 but there's always issues with Custom Connectors. This is the url it's hanging on https://api.pinterest.com/oauth/?client_id=xxxxxxxx&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2flogic-apis-westus.consent.azure-apim.net%2fredirect&state=2345dfhghg2-ce76-43c5-b7bc-efbf78d4c426&scope=boards%3aread%2c+pins%3aread
Any suggestions or thoughts welcomed!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From my testing, it looks like Microsoft enforce a space between Scope entries, which prevents Pinterest from authorising the oauth2 request. The Custom Connector can work if you only use one Scope e.g. user_accounts:read. So the workaround to use a Custom Connector with oAuth2 for the Pinterest API v5 is to create a connector for each Scope you want to use.

Can anyone raise a bug with Microsoft for this? Happy to provide more detailed info, but I don't have a support arrangement with MS.